# LINQ Check List<string> for multiple entries

Tags: c#, linq

Amazingly, I have not found a simple solution for the following behavior.

I have a List and I just want to check (with Linq) if there are multiple entries in it. That mean, i want to get a bool.

For Example:

```
List<string> listWithMultipleEntries = new List<string>()
{
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "!",
    "Hello"
};
```

This is maybe a solution I've ended with (I have not tested extensively but it seems to work)

```
if (listToCheck.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(y => y).Any())
{
    // Do something ...
}
```

but I would be surprised if there would not be any simpler solution
(I really have not found one)

Comment: You dont need the final `Select(y => y)` but other than that this or the current answer will do fine.

Comment: listWithMultipleEntries.Distinct().Count() == listWithMultipleEntries.Count;

Comment: Why does anybody use `Count()`? In most of the answers (and this question) a `.Skip(1).Any()` would completely work and would be much faster if you apply it on an `IEnumerable` that is not a `ICollection`.

Comment: @Oliver Can you give the whole linq statement please?

Comment: @veritas: Here we go: `listToCheck.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any()).Any()`. But I would remove the last `Any()` and iterate over the result to give feedback about what occurs multiple times.

Answer (score 8):

The group by option is probably the best but you could also do

```
if (listToCheck.Distinct().Count() != listToCheck.Count())
{
    // Do sth.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this should be the most efficient way to determine if a List has duplicates or not

```
public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    HashSet<T> distinct = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var s in list)
    {
        if (!distinct.Add(s))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

so you can..

```
if (listToCheck.HasDuplicates())
{
    // Do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ExtensionMethod` for such check. You can check if there are duplicates in many ways, but one of the simplest is:

```
public static bool ContainsDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return list.Any(element => list.Count(e => e.Equals(element)) > 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions, one using `GroupBy()`, the other using `Disctinct()`:

```
var hasDuplicates = listWithMultipleEntries.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);

var hasDuplicates = listWithMultipleEntries.Distinct().Count() != listWithMultipleEntries.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution might be to compare elements indexes :

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "!",
            "Hello"
        };

        bool hasDuplicates = list.Where((l, i) => list.LastIndexOf(l) != i).Any();

        Console.WriteLine(hasDuplicates);
```

Output : `true`